# Exported jar file wont execute

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I've created a runnable jar of my gui application, but when I click on it, it wont execute. Project runs fine within Eclipse though. I'm using JOGL and those jars are being called externally within Eclipse if that helps. Any idea as to why the jar wont execute?

Comment: Can you post the code of your UI_Mouse.java ?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly all the files that were raising problems did actually exist on the project, but were commented out (and thus, You didn't see them in the package explorer which is the view but you generally use).

After deleting them, everything shold be fine.

Comment: I had one class that was commented out, but after making the code visible, I just get the same warnings, but without "Class files on classpath not found or not..."

Answer (score 0):

Compile warnings should not stop you from creating the runnable jar. And there is no problem in replacing the already existing directory and dependencies.

Comment: I edited the question. The problem is that after the jar is created and clicked on, it wont run

Answer (score 0):

Could it be some issue with `MANIFEST.MF`? I remember having issues with that one and `jar` building myself. So you can build your app without having it filled in correctly. The problem is that your `jar` will not execute on simple double click (or opening it with `java -jar myapp`).

So your problem might be fixable by adding something like this to `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`:

```java
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: path.to.main.class
```